# WebSocket Unique ID

Tags: c#, websocket, httplistener

How can I differentiate between users in a secure manner using the standard WebSocketContext/HttpListenerContext? I have tried fetching httpListenerContext.User.Identity.Name but it throws an exception for some reason.